# how to configure private blockchain using bigchaindb .Is it possible?

Tags: blockchain, private, bigchaindb

Actually I found one blog  ('https://blog.bigchaindb.com/towards-a-public-bigchaindb-654619d93fac' ) here mentioned as it is public but in  https://www.bigchaindb.com/features/ this link in features it's like 'bigchaindb can be a public or private'.

how to configure bigchaindb as a private blockchain?.

What is role based access control in bigchaindb.